# Energy and Method used for Plasma separation in Ion thrusters?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, plasma-physics, propulsion

When I was thinking about Ion thrusters and their energy consumption, This popped into my mind. 
[image]

If the gas is being ionized in the chamber, there exist both positive and negative charges at the same time like a plasma. I know that separating a plasma into positive and negative particles takes a lot of energy. How is this done in an ion thrust, electrostatically? I think that the more dense the plasma is the harder it is to separate.

So my questions is how do ion thrusters do this and how much energy do they spend on this??

If possible, can somebody tell me the specific details like the plasma density in the ion thruster, electic potential of the walls.. etc??

Comment: It is no different than any other ion source - you manipulate the potential to make it favorable for the positive ions to head in one direction while the electrons try to stay away (one reason why the sketch is a little, well, sketchy).

Comment: How do you do that exactly? and wouldn't that need a lot of energy to succeed in separating them? can you please elaborate??

Comment: An isolated plasma is net neutral, with a sheath potential because the electrons are more mobile than the ions so they extend a bit further out. Bringing a negatively charged plate close to the isolated plasma will locally repel the electrons and attract the positive ions. Raising the entire plasma to a negative potential will mean ions are happy to accelerate away. The energy to separate them is the beam current times the accelerating voltage. (The inefficiency is in the plasma generation and beam optics).

Comment: But in the ion thruster that I am talking about I dont understand where the negative potential comes from. Since, almost everything is positively charged except for the last grid( The accelerator grid). But because there is a highly positive grid infront of that and positively charged walls, where does the negative potential come from? For some reason NASA's website says that the walls absorb the electrons. But I personally think that the plasma is strong enough to  withstand that (Debye length). Am I wrong about this??

Comment: There are mechanical forces at play here holding the walls in place (which plasmas do not have) and the number density of charged particles is relatively small compared to the number density of particles in the wall material.  If you properly "ground" the walls, this is not an issue (I use quotes around ground because there is no ground in space except the spacecraft and the surrounding plasma).